# Why List<dynamic> and not List<Map<String,dynamic>>?

Tags: json, types, dart

I have a small program that manipulates some JSON data with this structure:

```
{
    "categories": [{
        "id": 0,
        "title": "cat1"
    }],
    "drinks": [{
        "categoryId": 0,
        "image": "image",
        "title": "title",
        "text": "text"
    }]

}
```

Everything works well if I code using dynamic types or the *var* keyword but I am getting the following error  when I am declaring types.

`'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'`.

Here is that program:

```
import 'dart:convert';

main(List<String> args) {
  String source = ''' {
    "categories": [{
      "id": 0,
      "title": "cat1"
    }],
    "drinks": [{
      "categoryId": 0,
      "image": "image",
      "title": "title",
      "text": "text"
    }]
  }''';

  var json = jsonDecode(source);

  // Dynamic types, works ok!
  var categories = json['categories'];
  var title = categories[0]['title'];
  var id = categories[0]['id'];
  print('$title with $id');


  // Explicit types, error!
  List<Map<String,dynamic>> categories2 =  json['categories'];
  String title2 = categories2[0]['title'];
  int id2 = categories2[0]['id'];
  print('$title2 with $id2');

}
```

Why I am getting this error?  `categories` is of `List<dynamic>` type but why it's not a `List<Map<String,dynamic>>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart, the element type of a list is provided when the list is created, and it is kept as part of the list value. Every type you add an element to the list, it is checked to be of that type. This is unlike Java where generic type arguments are erased at runtime.

That means that a Dart `List<dynamic>` is not the same as a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, even if both lists contains only instances of `Map<String, dynamic>>`. For example, you can add an integer to the former and not to the latter.

A JSON list can contain any JSON value. 
In this case, your list contains only values that are maps, but that could be a coincidence. The JSON parser does not check the source code first to see if the list contains only one kind of objects, instead it just creates a `List<dynamic>` and puts the elements into that. The created list is mutable, so someone might add an integer to that list after it has been returned. That code would break if the parser made the list a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` instead.

So, your list is a `List<dynamic>` because all JSON lists created by `jsonParse` are that ... and it would be a breaking change to make them anything else.