# Declaring expected variable type cause error: type '(Map<String, dynamic>) => University' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax-error

I am using this logic to convert json data to a custom *University* model.

```
import 'dart:convert';
    
class UniversityWrapper {
  UniversityWrapper({
    this.isSuccess,
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  final bool isSuccess;
  final dynamic message;
  final List<University> data;

  factory UniversityWrapper.fromRawJson(String str) => UniversityWrapper.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory UniversityWrapper.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UniversityWrapper(
    isSuccess: json["is_success"],
    message: json["message"],
    data: json["data"] == null ? null : List<University>.from(json["data"].map((Map<String, dynamic> x) => University.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
    "is_success": isSuccess,
    "message": message,
    "data": data == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(data.map((University x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class University {
  University({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.cityId,
  });

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final int cityId;

  factory University.fromRawJson(String str) => University.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory University.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => University(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    cityId: json["city_id"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "city_id": cityId,
  };
}
```

The problem is in this line:

```
data: json["data"] == null 
   ? null 
   : List<University>.from(json["data"].map((Map<String, dynamic> x) => University.fromJson(x))),
```

If I set *x*'s type as **dynamic** or **nothing**, there isn't an error. Like *Example 1* and *Example 2*:

Example 1:

```
data: json["data"] == null 
       ? null 
       : List<University>.from(json["data"].map((dynamic x) => University.fromJson(x))),
```

Example 2:

```
data: json["data"] == null 
      ? null 
      : List<University>.from(json["data"].map((x) => University.fromJson(x))),
```

But the main question is, I don't understand why can't I set **Map<String, dynamic>** as a type of *x*. I think that I should be able to set it because *University.fromJson* method takes **Map<String, dynamic>**.

The method *University.fromJson*:

```
  factory University.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => University(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    cityId: json["city_id"],
  );
```

The error:

```
E/flutter ( 4780): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '(Map<String, dynamic>) => University' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => dynamic' of 'f'
E/flutter ( 4780): #0      new UniversityWrapper.fromJson (package:hb/models/university.dart:21:76)
E/flutter ( 4780): #1      _ProfilePageState.loadData (package:hb/ui/pages/profile.dart:118:66)
E/flutter ( 4780): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4780):
```

**Edit 1:** Example JSON Data:

```
 {   
    "is_success": true,   
    "message": null,   
    "data": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Abant İzzet Baysal Üniversitesi",
          "city_id": 14
        },
        {
          "id": 118,
          "name": "Acıbadem Üniversitesi",
          "city_id": 34
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Adıyaman Üniversitesi",
          "city_id": 2
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "Afyon Sağlık Bilimleri Üniversitesi",
          "city_id": 3
        }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: Can you please share the sample JSON too?

Comment: I shared info. But I don't think the problem at the parsing process.

Comment: Ok, there is a good explanation of your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55577750/10659482

Comment: `dynamic` is not the same as a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On reddit someone said:

> I think because when you decode and parse JSON, it gives you a general
> Dart object, not directly a map. So you have to cast it as a Map
> afterwards.
>
> Your fromJson method is expecting a Map<String, dynamic> argument, but
> you are passing an object (the decoded JSON) which you labeled as
> Map<String, dynamic>. I think it would work if you did
>
> fromJson(x as Map<String,dynamic>)
>
> instead of
>
> fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> x)
>
> dynamic or just "x" (which will be inferred as dynamic) works because
> having a dynamic type could mean anything and removes the strict
> checking

And in stackoverflow there is an explanation like that:

> In Dart, the element type of a list is provided when the list is
> created, and it is kept as part of the list value. Every type you add
> an element to the list, it is checked to be of that type. This is
> unlike Java where generic type arguments are erased at runtime.
>
> That means that a Dart List is not the same as a
> List<Map<String, dynamic>>, even if both lists contains only instances
> of Map<String, dynamic>>. For example, you can add an integer to the
> former and not to the latter.
>
> A JSON list can contain any JSON value. In this case, your list
> contains only values that are maps, but that could be a coincidence.
> The JSON parser does not check the source code first to see if the
> list contains only one kind of objects, instead it just creates a
> List and puts the elements into that. The created list is
> mutable, so someone might add an integer to that list after it has
> been returned. That code would break if the parser made the list a
> List<Map<String, dynamic>> instead.
>
> So, your list is a List because all JSON lists created by
> jsonParse are that ... and it would be a breaking change to make them
> anything else.

Thanks for the responses. My question has been answered. I am checking this post as a correct answer.